# how to cbind and keep latest columns if duplicated in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r

```
 df1
 a   b   c   d    e  
 1   2   3   4    5

 df2
 c   d   e 
 10  11  12
```

When I `cbind both df1 and df2` I want to retain columns of `df2`.
My final dataframe would be

```
 a  b  c   d   e
 1  2  10  11  12
```

How can I do it in r?

Comment: are you looking to replace values of df1 with df2 values for c, d, e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `modifyList` for this

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5)
df2 <- data.frame(c=10,d=11,e=12)

modifyList(df1, df2)
#   a b  c  d  e
# 1 1 2 10 11 12
```